# Spring component-scan does not work in Java main method

Tags: java, spring

This is a simple demo, it works with Eclipse, but does not work from the command line.

App.java:

```
ApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config/spring-application.xml");
context.getBean(MyService.class);
```

Spring-application.xml:

```
...
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.itest.service"></context:component-scan>
...
```

java command:

```
java -cp ./* com.itest.app.App
```

It runs with the java command, but the bean in `com.itest.service` package has not been initialized.

Comment: Is `MyService.class` file present in `./com/itest/service` directory (relatively to the current directory) when you launch your app from the command line? Or is it packages in some jar?

Comment: First of all thank you.I've solved it. 
There's a problem with the packing.When export the project with eclipse,  i choose the Runnable JAR file option, not the JAR file.The new jar contains all dependencies.